# How to Handle Json when Some time getting Object or Some Time getting Array using Retrofit

Tags: retrofit

I have facing Issues when we getting Some time JSON object and SOME Time JSON Array using Retrofit Libarary.
So Please suggest me How can Handle it.

Answer (score 1):

if your response is like  some times

```
{

    "accounts": {
      "AccountType": 
        {
           "accountId": 620430,
          "active": true,
        }

    },
    "code": "OK"

}
```

and some time

```
{

    "accounts": {
      "AccountType": [
        {
           "accountId": 620430,
          "active": true,
        },
 {
           "accountId": 620330,
          "active": true,
        }
      ]
    },
    "code": "OK"

}
```

then use these code , hope it will solve your problem

```
static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Accounts.class, new LocationsDeserializer()).create();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    ;



    public static  class LocationsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Accounts> {

        @Override
        public Accounts deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

            JsonElement monumentElement = json.getAsJsonObject().get("AccountType");
            if (monumentElement.isJsonArray()) {
                return new Accounts((AccountType[]) context.deserialize(monumentElement.getAsJsonArray(), AccountType[].class));
            } else if (monumentElement.isJsonObject()) {
                return new Accounts((AccountType) context.deserialize(monumentElement.getAsJsonObject(), AccountType.class));
            } else {
                throw new JsonParseException("Unsupported type of monument element");
            }
        }
    }
```

and your model class will be

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AccountResponse {

@SerializedName("accounts")
@Expose
private Accounts accounts;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;

public Accounts getAccounts() {
return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(Accounts accounts) {
this.accounts = accounts;
}

public String getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
this.code = code;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.AccountType.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AccountType {

@SerializedName("accountId")
@Expose
private Integer accountId;
@SerializedName("active")
@Expose
private Boolean active;

public Integer getAccountId() {
return accountId;
}

public void setAccountId(Integer accountId) {
this.accountId = accountId;
}

public Boolean getActive() {
return active;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
this.active = active;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Accounts.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Accounts {

@SerializedName("AccountType")
@Expose
private List<AccountType> accountType = null;

  public Accounts(AccountType ... ms) {
    accountType = Arrays.asList(ms);
}

public List<AccountType> getAccountType() {
return accountType;
}

public void setAccountType(List<AccountType> accountType) {
this.accountType = accountType;
}

}
```

Comment: but what type of model class create?

Comment: check the model class these may help you

Comment: could you paste your code  i amt clear about your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141630/discussion-between-vishal-and-chayon-ahmed).